# JSTL <c:set> body content exact specification

Tags: arrays, jsp, jstl

can someone suggest how possible to interpret `<c:set>` body?

- `<c:set var="movieList">One,Two,Three</c:set>`
- `<c:set var="movieList">"One","Two","Three"</c:set>`

in the first case `movieList` is a string and in the second it is an array `{"One", "Two", "Three"}`

what is `movieList` in these examples:

- `<c:set var="movieList">"On"e","Tw"o","Thr"ee"</c:set>`
- `<c:set var="movieList">"On\"e","Tw"o","Thr\"ee"</c:set>`

Comment: What makes you think any of those are arrays?  They're all just Strings.

Answer (score 3):

There's **no** difference in the interpreted Java type of the `c:set`'s body. It are in *all* cases just `String`.

Even when you set a non-String type as `c:set`'s body using EL such as

```
<c:set var="foo">${bean.someInteger}</c:set>
```

it'll be converted to `String` anyway by `String#valueOf()`.

Only when you process the variable afterwards, there *may* be difference, depending on how you processed it. For example,

```
<c:set var="movieList">One,Two,Three</c:set>
<c:set var="realMovieArray" value="${fn:split(movieList, ',')}" />
```

will result `${realMovieArray}` being a `String[]` with values of `One`, `Two` and `Three`.

Comment: it look like you are correct, but I find this example: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t124517-jstl-how-do-i-set-an-array-variable.html - take a look at last post in the thread. So I need some reference to specification...

Comment: That person is babbling nonsense. Such an answer would be downvoted into oblivion here so that it's for the unaware visitor clear that it's a bad answer.

Comment: @BalusC, that person was correct. Please reconsider your answer.

Comment: @DylanYi `String[] yankees = ...` and `<c:set var="yankees">...` is *not* the same thing. The first creates a string array, the second create a single string. As such, BalusC is correct saying it is nonsense. The fact that the `<c:forEach>` will iterate an array and that `<c:forEach>` will split and iterate a string, such that both *appear* to do the same thing, is an effect of how `<c:forEach>` is implemented, and has nothing to do with the `<c:set>`, and the question is *only* about `<c:set>`.

Comment: @Andreas, You're right. The two code fragments are not the same even if they result in the same output. I was only seeing the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="alphabet">A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z</c:set>

<c:forTokens items="${alphabet}" delims="," var="letter">
    ${letter}
</c:forTokens>
```